# MEV explore flashbots

Tags: solidity, flashbots, mev, arbitrage

What's the exact definition of `Outlier MEV txs currently in review` on Flashbot's MEV-explore [dashboard](https://explore.flashbots.net/leaderboard)?

Does it mean that the transactions there are currently under review and the profit (`MEV Tx Sender Income`) that's signaled might be wrong? Or is my interpretation wrong?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: these questions are better answered in the `newcomers` channel of Flashbot's Discrod group

Comment: Tried that already 5 times and no answer though @Nulik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is mentioned in [data & metrics](https://explore.flashbots.net/data-metrics) tab of the Explore, txs with huge amount of gas usage are separated and put in manual review:

> **Extracted MEV Gas Usage** % represents the overall gas usage of Extracted MEV txs as a % of the total gas usage on the Ethereum network since Jan 1 2020. We’ve added a filter on there to exclude the 5% most outlier value until they are reviewed manually.